# Dijkstra with forced movement constraint

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, shortest-path

Let's say I have an `N*N` 2D grid with weighted edges. Every movement I do on the grid has a constraint of always having a fixed X or Y component, that is: In **every** movement, I *have* to move 1 unit in the X coordinate and 3 in the Y coordinate.

I thought about removing edges I should not be walking through, but that doesn't address the fact that I must do these movements. How can I modify dijkstra (or any pathfinding algorithm, but preferably dijkstra) so it gives me the shortest path from A to B in this grid with these constraints?

Comment: Hint: go between points where you stop, not between points which you go through.

Comment: @Jan i didn't quite get it, what points do I stop?

Comment: I don't quite get it, you mind clarifying a bit? "Every movement I do on the grid has a constraint of always having a fixed X OR Y component" vs. "In every movement, I have to move 1 unit in the X coordinate AND 3 in the Y coordinate."... and what would the cost of a (1, 3) move be in a grid anyway - there are multiple ways to do the (1, 3) move, right?

Comment: @dingalapadum I meant that I could be restricted in either x axis, y axis, or both. The move doesn't take the cost into account - I have to move the specified amount no matter the cost of the move is

Comment: It still seems unclear to me: Let's say we're starting from (0, 0). I assume I can move to (1, 3), but if costs are defined between individual grid cells, there are several ways to do that: (0,0) -> (0, 1) -> (0, 3) -> (0, 3) -> (1, 3) or (0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (1. 2) -> (1, 3). Are either of those valid moves?

Comment: No, if you start in (0,0) and your movement restriction is (1,3), that is, always move 1 unit in X and 3 in Y, your available moves would be (1,3),(-1,3),(1,-3),(-1,-3). After moving to one of these, the same restriction would apply again

Comment: @JanDvorak's hint is good.  *Forget about* the fact that you have a grid -- build a *brand new* graph describing what you need to apply Dijkstra to.

Comment: @JanDvorak's hint means you don't need all points in the grid, there are some points you may never go, just concern about points that you MAY transverse to, and apply Dijkstra on the network / graph of those points.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time but I just wanna provide my perspective on the problem since there isn't a concrete answer yet.

Because there is a constraint on traversing the grid (similar to your example of having to move with a vector of (1,3) i.e. 1 in the X direction and 3 in the Y direction), when given a starting point, only a number of the cells will be reachable and they will form the graph on which we will perform our Dijkstra's algorithm. We can perform Dijkstra on the original grid itself and the unreachable nodes will have infinite distances from the source. However, this is very costly as we are effectively increasing the number of cells we have to examine in each iteration of the algorithm.

We can compute the graph of all reachable cells by performing a modified BFS. In each iteration of the search, only valid cells will be examined. "Valid" here means they satisfy the traversal constraint and that they reside within the original grid's range. For example, if we index all cells in a 6x6 grid using non-negative numbers starting at (0,0), and the constraint is (1,2), then if a BFS is performed on cell (0,0), the only valid neighbor will be (1,2). The BFS will then calculate the weight of the edge connecting (0,0) and (1,2) by choosing the less costly of the two possible routes: (0,0)->(0,1)->(1,1)->(1,2) and (0,0)->(0,1)->(0,2)->(1,2). Do this for all neighbors of (0,0), then all neighbors and its neighbors, and so on, just like regular BFS. The difference is that during a BFS iteration, when an already discovered cell is encountered, the edge weight between that cell and the cell that is being iterated in the BFS is still calculated (since we are making a graph with all possible and valid connections between the reachable cells, not just a BFS tree). At the end, we will have created our desired graph.

If the final destination is not in the resulting graph (we can have a set that keep tracks of all cells in the graph), then we conclude that there is no path from the source to the destination.

If the destination is in the graph, then we perform Dijkstra's algorithm as normal on the graph. The result would be the shortest path.